# Unrecognized selector sent to instance PDF display method

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a button with a selector calling a method, however I am receiving an error!

I set the method in .h

```
- (void)pdfPressed
```

then use it in .m

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"paper-plane-7.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:(DNavigationController *)self.navigationController action:@selector(pdfPressed)];

- (void)pdfPressed {
//...
```

However I am getting this error.

> -[DNavigationController pdfPressed]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x144e0fe60

Comment: When you're creating a button you specify target and selector.
Target is simply your object and selector specifies which method to call on target. In your example you're setting navigation controller as a target, so when you click on button your navigation controller would try to call pdfPressed method which doesn't exist and you'll get a crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"paper-plane-7.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(pdfPressed)];`